# Problem with materials after export

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export

I have a problem with a file exporter.
I made a 3d object with Cycles materials and when I export it and open it in some 3D viewer software, I cannot see any material on the exported object.
What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate? what type of material(s), what export format.

Comment: Materials are glossy BSDF and diffuse BSDF and i tried export to .obj and .fbx, but materials cant see...

Comment: I have a 3d model with materials (glossy, diffuse) and I want make a game using Unreal Engine 4, but in UE (.fbx) I see only white model + names of materials, but they are white. Btw. I'm using cycles render.

Comment: Edit those details into your question, it could be the exporter is not set up for cycles materials.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/materials-and-exporting-to-different-formats?rq=1.

Comment: More importantly, what 3D viewer are you using to view the item? I suspect that the cause is either that the 3D viewer, or the file formats you are using does not support cycles.

Comment: Well, then you should share your Solution with us =)

Comment: I'll change materials in UE :)

Comment: @Guyoslav good for you, but that sounds more like a workaround... if you could share even a basic stripped down version of your file - still having the problem - someone else could try to understand what's wrong, and maybe found a real better solution.