# How to show materials and textures in Model Viewer?

Tags: materials, export

I'm having trouble trying to see the materials and textures I assigned to some objects when I export the file in OBJ. all the objets look as the "Solid Mode" in Blender but I'm in ModelViewer.

What can I do? I saw a similar question here in the platform but couldn't follow the instruction correctly.

Comment: The .obj format (or more precisely the .mtl) can't represent Blenders node system, so the material will not look like the one in Blender. You can have a (single) texture assigned, which will also appear in the .mtl file referenced by the .obj (if the texture is already saved on your hard drive)

Comment: Thank you! I'm putting textures now. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I save something as an OBJ file the texture does not save with it, why?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/when-i-save-something-as-an-obj-file-the-texture-does-not-save-with-it-why)

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/materials-and-exporting-to-different-formats?rq=1